# Connecting to server using xrdp leads to grayed out screen

Tags: 14.04, server, remote-desktop, xrdp

Recently after the upgrade, connecting to a server using xrdp leads to a 'grayed out' screen. Please help to solve the issue.

```
#apt-cache policy xrdp
xrdp:
  Installed: 0.6.0-1
  Candidate: 0.6.0-1

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

# apt-cache policy gnome-session
gnome-session:
  Installed: 3.9.90-0ubuntu12.1
  Candidate: 3.9.90-0ubuntu12.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.9.90-0ubuntu12.1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.9.90-0ubuntu12 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

I could also see it is a bug and a patch is provided in the below link. Please guide me how to fix the same(as i am relatively new to ubuntu).
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281

Comment: How does the affected RDP client connect to the server? How is the RDP server configured? What upgrade are you talking about? Can you describe the symptoms of the problem with more detail, please? A screenshot may say more than a thousand words.

Comment: Can't add a screenshot as i dont have enough reputation points.. But all i could say is that screen is grayed out with checkboxes.

Comment: Even with low reputation you can still add links to images.

Comment: David, i updated the question. However i am new to ubuntu. Can you please guide to fix using the patch provided in the link.

Comment: The [bug, you mention](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281), has been fixed in Trusty since April. Please make sure, that your software packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The xrdp and grey screen is a known issue.  As far as I know, no fix has been provided yet with Ubuntu and gnome-session.  To have xrdp working with Ubuntu, you have to perform the following process

**step 1** : install xrdp package

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

**step 2** : install alternate desktop (in this example - we install mate-desktop).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
```

**Step 3** : tell the system to use mate-desktop interface when connecting through xrdp.from terminal session, type the following command

```
sudo sed -i.bak ‘/fi/a #xrdp multiple users configuration \n echo mate-session >~/.xsession \n’ /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh**
```

Full instructions and details about this issue can be found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952).